# missing domain in continue url

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I am trying to Authenticate with Firebase Using an Email Link in React native and expo.
Here is my code

```
    const actionCodeSettings = {
      url: 'ndimensions-9c677.web.app',
      handleCodeInApp: true,
  };

       emailAuth: async (email) => {
          try {
            firebase.auth().sendSignInLinkToEmail(email, actionCodeSettings)
              .then(() => {
                // The link was successfully sent. Inform the user.
                // Save the email locally so you don't need to ask the user for it again
                // if they open the link on the same device.
                window.localStorage.setItem('emailForSignIn', email);
                // ...
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                const errorCode = error.code;
                const errorMessage = error.message;
                console.log(errorCode, errorMessage);
                // ...
              });
          } catch (error) {
            console.log('Something went wrong with Email Link Authentication: ', error);
          }
        },
```

I am getting the errors: **auth/invalid-continue-uri Missing domain in continue url**
What should be the value of url?

Answer (score 22):

You are missing the protocol for the URL, eg.
url: 'https://ndimensions-9c677.web.app'